# How to create donut chart in pure css & svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I need to create a simple Donut Chart with filled-up animation. My donut chart needs to be divided into 4 sections of 4 different colors.
I need to do it in pure css or pure svg and need to control it from javascript (meaning that the input needs to come from the `.js` file.
I would like to know how to create basic Donut chart in css or svg,thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out chartJS.  There's a doughnut chart, and it's pure javascript controlled and writes to a HTML5 canvas.  So you can easily export an SVG or whatever.

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart

Comment: thx for the quick respond, I am familiar with this library and I don't want to use any external js lib, this way I said donut chart in css or svg.

Comment: What specifically is your question? You do not ask any question at all.

Comment: how to create donut chart in css or svg?

Comment: you can generate svg code based on your data. Where is your problem?